# How to approach factoring problems?

Tags: calculus, integration, factoring

Generally speaking, how should I approach a problem involving factoring?  I usually don't have a problem with the more typical forms, but sometimes I just don't know what to do.

My calc2 question is this:

The given curve is rotated about the y-axis.  Find the area of the resulting surface.

$$y = \frac{1}{4}x^2- \frac{1}{2}\ln x,\quad 1 \le x \le 3$$

So the first thing I did was this:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{2x}$$

And then this:

$$1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{\!2}= 1 + \frac{1}{4}x^2-\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{4x}$$

I was then able to simplify it down to this:

$$\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4x^2}$$

But leaving it in this form doesn't make it an easy integral to deal with.  My solution manual shows them simplifying it to this:

$$\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{2x}\right)^{\!2}$$

And I have no idea how to get from the form I was in to the form above.  Is there any strategy, technique, books or videos I can read to strengthen my factoring ability?

Lastly, how did they get to that form above?

Comment: Since you know the answer is you could multiply out $(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{2x})$, then try to reverse engineer the process. Also know the art of factoring is to a large extent an exercise in pattern recognition (their are some procedures in some special cases like quadratics), so you get good at it by doing lots of them. Another point that ncmathsadist brings up in the answer is that when you have some sum of ratios, it is a often good idea to put them over a common denominator (In general, it is a good idea to put an expression into multiple forms).

Comment: @BabyDragon Thank you for that advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4x^2} = {x^4 + 2x^2 + 1\over 4x^2}.$$
The denominator is a perfect square; now factor
$${x^4 + 2x^2 + 1\over 4x^2} = {(x^2 + 1)^2\over 4x^2} = \left(x^2 + 1\over 2x\right)^2. $$

Does this make it less opaque?

Comment: I see, so find a common denominator, and then factor the numerator and the denominator?  I guess my issue is seeing the pattern.  I started to do what you have explained above, but I just didn't *see* the perfect square in the denominator.